# Bad performance in jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm really unexperienced with jQuery but I've been reading tutorials for a week now and this is my first code. It works, however it starts to perform badly after a while. Especially when the mouseenter/mouseleave action is called several times in a row. For every time the delay increases untill I move to another element.

I've googled about for bad performance in jQuery but had no luck. The best I found was the tip: "*Use ID's instead of class selectors (JQuery)*" but I'm not sure of why that would be the problem and I find it hard to replace the '.photo' for an id-tag since it's supposed to be affecting several elements.

I also found "*Generally, JavaScript is faster when you search or alter the DOM as little as possible.*" Could that be my problem, and if so, how would I do it otherwise?

So please let me know if something looks odd in my code or if you have any idea. Thanks!

**CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".photo").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.9);
    });
    $(".photo").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.6);
    });
    $('.photo').click(function() {
        $(this).animate({width: '900px'});
        $(this).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).animate({width: '294px'});
        });
    });

    $('.trigger').click(function() {
        if( $("#5").is(":hidden") ) {
            $("#6").hide('slow');
            $('.trigger').fadeTo('slow', 0);
        } else if ( $("#4").is(":hidden") ){
            $("#5").hide('slow');
        } else if ( $("#3").is(":hidden") ){
            $("#4").hide('slow');
        } else if ( $("#2").is(":hidden") ){
            $("#3").hide('slow');
        } else if ( $("#1").is(":hidden") ){
            $("#2").hide('slow');
        } else {
            $("#1").hide('slow');
            $(".triggerR").fadeTo('slow', 1);
        }
    });

    $('.triggerR').click(function() {
        if( $("#6").is(":hidden") ) {
            $("#6").toggle('slow');
            $(".trigger").fadeTo('slow', 1);
        } else if( $("#5").is(":hidden") ) {
            $("#5").toggle('slow');
        } else if ( $("#4").is(":hidden") ){
            $("#4").toggle('slow');
        } else if ( $("#3").is(":hidden") ){
            $("#3").show('slow');
        } else if ( $("#2").is(":hidden") ){
            $("#2").show('slow');
        } else if ( $("#1").is(":hidden") ){
            $("#1").show('slow');
            $(".triggerR").fadeTo('slow', 0);
        } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are queuing up different animations. Cancel all qued animations with the `stop` function on your animations before doing another animation.

[.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$(this).stop(true, true).fadeTo("fast", 0.9);
```

EDIT: Upon @guffa's advice to maintain opacity better use

```
$(this).stop(true, false).fadeTo("fast", 0.9);
```

Comment: I think that `stop(true, false)` would be better, so that the animation continues from the current opacity and not jumps to the other opacity setting first.

Comment: Thanks alot, it works smooth! It had to be (true, true) in my case otherwise animations could be stopped in the midst of their supposed behaiovour. Great input though! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you have lots of elements with the "photo" class, and you add a different listener to all of them.

I'm not sure how you would avoid that for mouseenter / mouseleave, but you could use 
[event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) for the click ...

Comment: I think the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events bubble up the DOM, so event delegation would still work for them.

Comment: Right ! There is indeed both a "currentTarget" and a "relatedTarget" property on the "mouseenter" event, so you could find the actual photo that triggered it. Thanks https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/mouseover

Answer (score 0):

These are minimal optimisations, so you won't see a huge performance boost from them, but instead of doing:

```
$('.photo').mouseenter(...);
$('.photo').mouseleave(...);
$('.photo').click(...);
```

You'd instead chain the functions so you only do `$('.photo')` once:

```
$('.photo').mouseenter(...).mouseleave(...).click(...);
```

Also take a look at your `if` conditions where you're selecting the same element multiple times; you can save the result into a variable:

```
var foo = $('#6');
```

then use `foo` rather than doing `$('#6')` repeatedly.

This is a bit bigger, but you're adding an event handler inside an event handler. Every time you click on a `.photo` element, you add another `mouseleave` event handler; they will build up, and probably cause the page to slow down.

Comment: Thanks alot, very helpful tips! Especially the last one that Guffa also mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

There is two problems with the code. First, if the `mouseenter` and `mouseleate` events happen before the previous animation is finsihed, the animations will be queued. If you move in and out several times fast, you will see all the animations for that playing out until the animation queue is empty.

Stop any previos animation before starting the new:

```
$(".photo").mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).stop().fadeTo("fast", 0.9);
});
$(".photo").mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).stop().fadeTo("fast", 0.6);
});
```

Second, in the `click` event handler you are registering another `mouseleave` event, so if you click several times you will have several event handlers adding animations whenever you leave the element. You won't see the animations because they will animate the size from 294px to 294px, but all the animations are queued up and will be in the way for other animations.

Unbind the `mouseleave` event handler when you have used it:

```
$('.photo').click(function() {
  $(this).animate({width: '900px'});
  function handler() {
    $(this).unbind('mouseleave', handler);
    $(this).animate({width: '294px'});
  }
  $(this).mouseleave(handler);
});
```

Comment: Great feedback! Thanks alot! A robust explanation in my level of understanding!